# How to get pid and process exist code of last shell command

Tags: shell

I know that $! would give me the pid of last command, and $? would give me the exit value of last command, but how can I get both of them in one shell command ? Thanks

Comment: Try: `command &; echo $! && echo $?`.

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer**

It is impossible to get both PID and exit status in one command. You need at least two commands: one to save the PID (`$!`), another to `wait` and get the exit code (`$?`).

**Description**

According to the [documentation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_02):

> `!` Expands to the decimal process ID of the most recent background command (see Lists) executed from the current shell.

So `$!` is not expanded to "the PID of last command", you need to schedule a command for execution in background using `&` after the command, for instance.

It is impossible to get exit code of a command until it exits -- we need to `wait`. The `wait` command

> Returns the status of the last ID; fails if ID is invalid or an invalid
> option is given.

(where `ID` is the last positional argument passed to the command.)

**Example**

```
ls >/dev/null 2>&1 &

pid=$!
wait $pid
exit_code=$?
printf 'PID: %d Exit code: %d\n' $pid $exit_code
```

Note that `$!`

> Expands to the decimal process ID of the most recent background command

Refer to the [Shell Command Language Special Parameters](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_02) for the information about special shell parameters such as `$!`, `$?` and others.